# System.FormatException While Convert to Byte

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I Got an Error while compiling this code for my encrypting class, it say "Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll"

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
        bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    return bytes;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you just use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes?

Comment: @ViVi that's the same code the OP uses.

Comment: @Richard what is the string? A hex string can only contain digits and letters between A and F. Perhaps the message is correct? Post an example that reproduces the problem

Comment: No repro when an actual hex string is used.

Comment: Indeed, as @PanagiotisKanavos says try it with a string such as `FFFFFF` and you'll get the result `255,255,255`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I meant to check the other answers

Comment: @Vivi why? There's nothing wrong with this code as long as the input is valid

Comment: this is my input : "7b35872759c064993c9d510ef150122f mnbvcxzlkjhgfdsa qwertyuiopasdfgh"

Comment: That's *not* a valid hex string. The first "word" is a hex string. The next two words are not - they contain all sorts of invalid letters. In fact, it looks like someone just hit one line of keys after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the input is invalid. A hex string can only contain digits and characters between A and F.

Using the string `A3AEEEF4` with the following code returns four bytes:

```
var     bytes=StringToByteArray("A3AEEEF4");   
Console.WriteLine("Length {0}. Content: {1}", bytes.Length,String.Join("-",bytes));
---------
> Length 4. Content: 163-174-238-244
```

The string `AZAEEEF4` though isn't a valid hex string because the second letter is `Z`. This will raise a `FormatException` with the message `Additional non-parsable characters are at the end of the string.`

In fact, this is the correct exception for this situation. This is indeed a malformed hex string.

You could add exception handling to the method to return the character pair that caused the error, eg:

```
byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    {
        var pair=hex.Substring(i, 2);
        try
        {
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(pair, 16);
        }
        catch (FormatException exc)
        {
            throw new FormatException($"Invalid pair {pair} at {i}", exc);
        }
        return bytes;
}
```

or you can use [Byte.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkktxbeh(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid throwing two exceptions:

```
byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
    {
        var pair=hex.Substring(i, 2);
        if (!byte.TryParse(pair, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           out bytes[i / 2]))
        {
            throw new FormatException($"Invalid pair {pair} at {i}");
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to run program with your code and seems like they've no problem so far.
Unless "String hex" contains any character that's not hex string (0-9, A-F), It'll occurred with the same error as you. Make sure that your input parameter aren't contains any character that isn't hex string.

Comment: Your answer comes down to either "non-repro" or "check your input". That's a reason to close a question, not to answer it.

Comment: Since I can't comment the post so I'm replying as answer instead. I'm really sorry if its bothering anyone.